# Number of ratings decreasing in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have noticed, that the **number of ratings** for one of my apps is only decreasing last 2 days: it was 374, yesterday when I refreshed was 365, today is 364.

I have tried to contact Google support, since I think it is not possible to "unrate" an app, so this sounds like a bug to me, however, I was not able to find a suitable question/but report form.

My question is: does anyone know something about this issue, or generally how the number of ratings (**not the rating itself!**) could go down?

Alternatively, a bug report form would be appreciated too.

P.S. link to the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rts.android.spacesim

Comment: same here. i lost like 10% of the ratings in last day. and i have no idea what's happening.

Comment: I guess it is not the delete button, can't imagne a dozen of people decided to delete their ratings just in that special day. I guess Google cleaned up comments due to some reason, but was unable to find it so far.

Comment: no, it's not. my reviews just got back today :)

Comment: Yep, same happened for my app. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8xYw.png) there is a delete button above My Review, when you click it you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LS2U.png).